# Problems with Babel italian in TeXLive-2015

Tags: babel

I met with problems with Babel italian after upgrading to TeXLive-2015 on a iMac 27 (OS X Yosemite 10.10.5). The very same file runs smoothly if using TeXLive-2014. Any suggestion?

My preamble:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{appendix} % more flexible treatment of the appendices
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel} % Il testo è in italiano
.........
```

My console output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Storia_Famiglia_Budinich.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/Users/mbh/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/appendix/appendix.sty)
(/Users/mbh/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/babel/babel.sty
(/Users/mbh/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/babel/english.ldf
(/Users/mbh/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/babel/babel.def))
(/Users/mbh/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/babel/italian.ldf
/Users/mbh/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/babel/italian.ldf:91: Undefined control
 sequence.
\@initiate@active@char ...e }}{}\else \@activated 
                                                  {#1}\@namedef {normal@char...
l.91 \initiate@active@char{"}
                             %
? 
........
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that you have several files in your personal TeX tree, that are probably outdated. Retry after having renamed `~/Library/texmf` into `~/Library/texmf-NO`, which would exclude them from being “seen” by TeX programs.

Comment: Correct! Was my fault, thks, MB

Comment: In this case I'll vote for closing the question as off topic. Don't worry about that, it's just that we lack better named reasons: without anybody seeing the log file, it would have been difficult to make a diagnosis. Well shaped question, by the way! Keep it up TeXing! Ciao.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated file in the OP's personal tree.